# Invalid write error from valgrind on this piece of code

Tags: c

Valgrind detect an invalid write of size 1 in this piece of code.
In this, I read a file where the first line is something I don't need, and the following lines define 3 strings and 1 int (total_space) that I need to put in this struct:

```
typedef struct 
{
    char username[40];   
    char password[40];   
    char token[40];     
    pid_t logged_pid;    
    int  total_space;    
    int  used_space;    
} User;
```

The file is this (each word on a new line, sorry but I still didn't understand how to format text and code):

```
pass 
username1 
password1 
token1delczzzzozoc 
4500000 
username2 
pasword2222 
token2efwerfg 
trg 
1000000
```

Here is the code: valgrind yells only in the first 4 lines! And in the first one on the character "e": what's wrong with it?

```
User *user = NULL;
int n = 0;
int k = 0;
char input;
FILE *file;            

if(!(file = fopen(USERS, "r")))    logMmboxd("opening USERS failed\n", 1);  
else                               logMmboxd("opened USERS\n", 0);  

/* file pointer at the second line, since the first has nothing i need now */
while((input = fgetc(file)) != EOF && input != '\n')   {}

/* read 4 lines every loop from the second line to the EOF */
while((input = fgetc(file)) != EOF)   
{  
    /* rewind the pointer to the previous character (the one I read to see if the file ended) */
    if(fseek(file, -1, SEEK_CUR) == -1)   logMmboxd("failed seeking USERS\n", 1);

    /* expand the array of 1 user */
    users = realloc(users, n+1);
    n++;    

    for(k=0; (input=fgetc(file)) != '\n' && input != EOF; k++)   users[n-1].username[k] = input;
    users[n-1].username[k+1] = '\0';    

    for(k=0; (input=fgetc(file)) != '\n' && input != EOF; k++)   users[n-1].password[k] = input;
    users[n-1].password[k+1] = '\0';    

    for(k=0; (input=fgetc(file)) != '\n' && input != EOF; k++)   users[n-1].token[k] = input;
    users[n-1].token[k+1] = '\0';   

    users[n-1].logged_pid = 0;

    for(k=0; (input=fgetc(file)) != '\n' && input != EOF; k++)   line[k] = input;
    line[k+1] = '\0';   
    users[n-1].total_space = atoi(line);    

    users[n-1].used_space = usedSpace(users[n-1].username);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
/* expand the array of 1 user */
users = realloc(users, n+1);
```

Expands `users` by one byte, not one `User`.

Comment: LOL. Thanks... users = realloc(users, sizeof(User)*(n+1)).

Answer (score 1):

```
char input;
```

should be:

```
int input;
```

otherwise EOF may not be detected correctly. And whenever I see a call to `realloc()` I always shudder.

Comment: Input is the character read from time to time with fgetc, why should it be an int?

Comment: @hysoka44 Because fgetc() returns an int.